# How to not use loops & IF-statements in R

Tags: r, loops, nested, apply

I have two dataframes in R, one big but imcomplete (import) and I want to create a smaller, complete subset of it (export). Every ID in the $unique_name column is unique, and does not appear twice. Other columns might be for example body mass, but also other categories that correspond to the unique ID. I've made this code, a double-loop and an if-statement and it does work, but it is slow:

```
for (j in 1:length(export$unique_name)){
  for (i in 1:length(import$unique_name)){
    if (toString(export$unique_name[j]) == toString(import$unique_name[i])){
      export$body_mass[j] <- import$body_mass[i]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not very good with R but I know this is a bad way to do it. Any tips on how I can do it with functions like apply() or perhaps the plyr package?

Bjørn

Comment: See `merge`. This is a join operation.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but isn't it just export <- import[!is.na(import$body_mass), ]  or if you want all columns to be complete export <- import[complete.cases(import), ]

Comment: Thanks  A.Webb, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many functions to do this. check out..

```
library(compare)
compare(DF1,DF2,allowAll=TRUE)
```

or as mentioned by @A.Webb `Merge` is pretty handy function.

```
merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by.x = "Unique_ID",by.y = "Unique_ID", all.x = T, sort = F)
```

If you prefer SQL style statements then

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT * FROM DF1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM DF2')
```

easy to implement and to avoid `for` and `if` conditions

Comment: Thanks for the help (and everyone else). Like you and  A.Webb say, Merge() is exactly what im looking for! This makes things very easy.

Answer (score 0):

As A.Webb suggested you need join:

```
    # join data on unique_name
    joined=merge(export, import[c("unique_name", "body_mass")], c('unique_name')) 
    joined$body_mass=joined$body_mass.y  # update  body_mass  from import to export
    joined$body_mass.x=NULL  # remove not needed column
    joined$body_mass.y=NULL  # remove not needed column
    export=joined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:As shown below use "which" function .This would reduce the loop iterations

```
for (j in 1 : nrow(export)){
          index<- which(import$unique_name %in% export$unique_name[j])
          if(length(index)=1)
          {
            export$body_mass[j] <- import[index[1],"body_mass"]
          }
        }
```